# Get the Order Id from Tracking Id

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get the Order Id from Tracking Id

In below image, this is tracking id : 371610055926

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (untested code)

```
$trackId = '123456';
$track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->load($trackId, 'track_number');
if ($track) {
    $orderId = $track->getShipment()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
} else {
    //tracking does not exist
}
```

Comment: no need to test when you posted an answer :)